# Como posso fazer uma estrutura de repetição aqui?(Fortran)

Tags: loop, fortran

```
program equacao
implicit none
real a,b,c,q
real x3,x2,x1
character s,n,read,if

complex sqrt

100 print*, "Esse programa calcula equacoes do 2 grau"

write (*,*) "De os valores de a, b, c(respectivamente)"
read (*,*) a,b,c

q = (b**2)-4*a*c
x1 = (-b+sqrt(q) ) / (2*a)
x2 = (-b-sqrt(q) ) / (2*a)
x3 = (-b) / 2*a

if (q .lt. 0) then
 print*, "Nao existe x real"
endif

if (q .gt. 0) then
 print*, "delta=",q
 print*, "X' e X'' respectivamente=",x1,"e",x2
elseif (q .eq. 0) then
 print*, "So existe uma raiz"
 print*, x3
endif

write (*,*) "Calcular mais uma?(s/n)"
read (*,*) s,n
if (read .eq. s) then
   do while (if .eq. s)
      goto 100
   enddo
elseif (read .eq. n) then
    do while (if .eq. n)
       goto 200
    enddo
endif
stop
200 end
```

Answer (score 2):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> • Se entendi a pergunta, experimente **remover**  <kbd>**`do while`**</kbd>   **dentro** do  <kbd>**`if`**</kbd>:

**Obs. 1 :** O que você deseja com as variáveis **`read & if`** eu näo entendi, então removi essas variáveis e substitui **`s & n`** por **`sn`**.

**Obs. 2 :** Adicionado a variável **`ierr`** para um **verificação** do  input **diferente** do tipo de **variável** esperada nas **leituras** **`a,b,c`** e  **`sn`**,  fazendo o **redirecionando** para a **pergunta pertinente**.

```FORTRAN
program equacao
implicit none

integer ierr
complex sqrt
character(1) sn
real a,b,c,q,x3,x2,x1

100 write(*,*)char(10),'Esse programa calcula equacoes do 2 grau'

write (*,*)char(10),"De os valores de a, b, c (respectivamente)"
read (*,*,iostat=ierr) a,b,c
if (int(ierr) .ne. int(0.)) go to 100

 q = (b**2)-4*a*c
x1 = (-b+sqrt(q) ) / (2*a)
x2 = (-b-sqrt(q) ) / (2*a)
x3 = (-b) / 2*a

if (q .lt. 0.) print*, char(10),"Nao existe x real"

if (q .gt. 0.) then
   print*,char(13),"delta = ",q
   print*,"X e X respectivamente = ",x1," e ",x2
elseif (q .eq. 0.) then
   print*, "So existe uma raiz"
   print*, x3
endif

300 write (*,*) char(10),"Calcular mais uma?(s/n)"

read (*,'(a1)') sn
if (int(ierr) .ne. int(0.)) go to 300

if (sn .eq. "s" .or. sn .eq. "S") then
   goto 100
elseif (sn .eq. "n" .or. sn .eq. "N") then
   goto 200
else 
   goto 300
endif

200 end program equacao
```